# Create .exe file under Ubuntu in with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-8

I created JavaFX application under Ubuntu and I need to create exe file.
Is it possible to do that under Linux?

Comment: There is the [JavaFX Packager Tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html), but for some reason it can only produce packages for the platform it's running on, so to produce an EXE/MSI you must run it on Windows.

Comment: Same thing. Looks like the only way is to do that under windows.

Comment: Thanks for the accept ;-)

Comment: Better late than never ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess by "exe" file you are referring to a "standalone binary" that doesn't require its users to have a JRE installed on their system.

Short answer: no, that isn't really an option in practical reality.

What you can do instead: deploy your whole application into a single JAR and use a script [wrapper](https://coderwall.com/p/ssuaxa/how-to-make-a-jar-file-linux-executable) around it. That makes it easier for folks to invoke your JAR.

For the "long" answer on creating binaries; see [here](https://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html).

Comment: By "exe" I mean portable app for Windows.
Does jar wrapper for windows exists?

Comment: no, it is not possible, as stated by the [docu](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html#A1307236) and [rejected JDK bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091902 )